# How to setup ALE with clang?

Tags: filetype-c++, plugin-ale

I'm trying to setup ALE with clang but apparently clang has no idea about my source files - it cannot find included files for a start.

How can I tell ALE/clang were are all my sources?

If you already use ALE with clang(or other C/C++ related) it would be helpful to see other setups.

Thanks!

Comment: let g:ale_c_clang_options="-I/path/to/headers"? let g:ale_cpp_clang_options="-I/path/to/headers"?